# Que retorna el hash?

Tags: javascript

No he encontrado , que cosa retorna si hago:

```
if (window.location.hash = '')
```

Siendo la web `http://eduard.com`

Comment: Falta incluir detalles sobre lo buscado/investigado. Referencia [ask].

Comment: A ver, dices que no has encontrado... Bueno, creo que aquí haré una excepción a mis reglas personales: click aquí http://lmgtfy.com/?q=window.location.hash ahora ya encontraste, ponte a leer :D que para ser buen programador, debe ser inexistente esa excusa de "no hay información", disculpa si te incomoda, las cosas como son. Por otro lado un IF statement debe tener dos signos igual para hacer comparación y si deseas ser más exacto, utiliza tres signos igual === revisa este enlace: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ y entenderás a mayor detalle las comparaciones en JavaScript

Comment: Si recién andas aprendiendo JavaScript, te presento tu nueva biblia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript aquí tienes la documentación en español :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No debería retornar nada con esa `URL` , el `hash` como su nombre lo indica obtiene el `#` y lo qué está después de este

**Ejm**

```
http://eduard.com  // retorna vacío 
http://eduard.com#hola  // retorna #hola
```

El valor que retorna si no hay *hash* será una *string* vacío , una forma de comprobar el valor que retorna sería

```
var x = window.location.hash;
console.log(typeof x);  // return string
```

Otra cosa es tener en cuenta es que en el `if` la comparación sería con `==` , es decir

```
if (window.location.hash == ''){... //Sin Hash}
```

Comment: Sisé , solo que lo escribí a la rápida, pero que retorna?, no entendí.

Comment: null? undefined? false?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian añadí algo adicional , retorna un `string` vacío simplemente.